# How to download an image(jpg) from Server using HttpWebRequest And NetworkCredential

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Very new to httpWebRequest and NetworkCredential for Windows phone 7 or Silverlight for Windows phone 7. It seems they are very different from the previous .net version. Hope someone can show me an sample code for the above to learn from. Would appreciate your help.

I am lost:

```
HttpWebRequest httpReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://xxx/myImage.jpg"));
httpReq.BeginGetResponse(HTTPWebRequestCallBack, httpReq);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, maybe helpfull to you

```
HttpWebRequest reqest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("your url");
reqest.BeginGetResponse(ReadCallback, reqest);
//callback method defination........

void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    HttpWebResponse responce = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(result);
    Stream s = responce.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader str = new StreamReader(responce.GetResponseStream());
    {
        nowparsingstring = str.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind go take a look at WebClient class. It has more convinient methods for downloading images.

Here is msdn example code:

```
string remoteUri = "http://www.contoso.com/library/homepage/images/";
string fileName = "ms-banner.gif", myStringWebResource = null;
// Create a new WebClient instance.
WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
// Concatenate the domain with the Web resource filename.
myStringWebResource = remoteUri + fileName;
Console.WriteLine("Downloading File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\" .......\n\n", fileName, myStringWebResource);
// Download the Web resource and save it into the current filesystem folder.
myWebClient.DownloadFile(myStringWebResource,fileName);        
Console.WriteLine("Successfully Downloaded File \"{0}\" from \"{1}\"", fileName, myStringWebResource);
Console.WriteLine("\nDownloaded file saved in the following file system folder:\n\t" + Application.StartupPath);
```

Comment: serafin: Would appreciate if you could show the the HttpWebRequest Method. Understand WebClient is a Wrapper and may have other issues. Thanks